# bootstrap-datepicker implementation

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I hope someone can help me with this little problem. I think it's simple but not being a javascript,html guy; I am finding it a bit difficult to implement it.

Basically I am using bootstrap-datepicker that I'd like to implement.

I found the following website that allows me to tweak a calendar and provides the appropriate code.
[bootstrap_dsatepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=embedded&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=linked&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=true&multidateSeparator=&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)

I am trying to implment the inline/embedded calendar and the following code is given

```
$('#sandbox-container div').datepicker({
multidate: true
```

});

But I am not sure how to implement the sandbox-container

In my html I did the following

```
<script>
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    multidate:true
})
```

and then

```
 <div class="datepicker">
        </div>
```

If I call datepicker in the script, it work but the calendar theme isn't the same as the one shown by the sandbox-container. Plus even in the datepicker I am not being able to tweak(add multidate etc)

How can I implement the code properly?

PS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/bootstrap-3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen, projection">

<script>
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        multidate:true
    })
</script>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <h5>Pickup Dates</h5>
<div class="datepicker">
</div>


</div>
```

These are the related code that is being used. The library that I am using a lot more but I believe 
I have all the libraries. If you believe that problem is related to file references then I will appreciate if you can tell me what files are required so I can check if I have referenced them or have them present.

================================
I have asked a question about how to implement the calendar that I'm using with angularjs.
I found a way to do it which is not 100% angular but it works well

I've added an ng-click in the datepick tag as follow:

```
<div class="datepicker"  ng-click="test()" ></div>
```

In my controller I have created a function(called test() in this case) and I use the jquery method to pass the dates that have been selected:

```
  $scope.test=function(){
        $scope.selectedDates=$('.datepicker').datepicker('getDates');
    }
```

A list of dates are added/removed automatically as you select the dates from the calendar.
I hope it helps

Comment: Can you show us a sample of your html code? What files have you referenced? Is the script under the div?

Comment: I have added some extra information.

Comment: some css should be there for bootstrap datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error, you defined jquery after bootstrap-datepicker. It is highly likely that datepicker depends on jquery.

Second error, you had your script befor the div was ready, so at the time the script was run the div did not exist.

It is good to have references in the head section and keep in mind that the order matters, and have your scripts on the bottom of the body section, so you can make sure your dom elements have been loaded on time.

```
<script src="/resources/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/bootstrap-3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen, projection">



<div class="col-md-3">
    <h5>Pickup Dates</h5>

    <!--Inline DatePicker-->
    <div class="datepicker">
    </div>
    <script>
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            multidate:true
        })
    </script>
    <!--------------------->



    <!--Sandbox DatePicker-->
    <div id="sandbox-container">
        <input class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
        });
    </script>
    <!--------------------->


</div>
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e7L3bwuw/)**

Comment: Thank you, having changed the order now the calendar theme has changed and it looks like the one in link provided earlier.
However,can't click on dates, nothing is highlighter, can only change months.

Comment: how should it look like?

Comment: Thanks alot for the jdfiddle. After checking it out, I realized that datepicker3.css is required. I've added that and it works perfectly.
Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Oh, for some reason i thought you had included it but not show it in your sample...:-)

Comment: you're right, I said that I have some other files as well but because I had too many files referenced I didn't want to include all of them and wasn't 100% which ones might be relevant :)

Comment: I have an additional question and hope to be helped with it.
Usually I define an ng-model and that can be hooked with my controller to store,set values. In this case I am defining an ng-model but it doesn't work

<div class="datepicker"  ng-model="selectedDates"></div>

How can I implement this? THanks

Comment: I have been working with a different datepicker. You may check out http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . Go to directives section and you will find a datepicker to use with angular and which is bootstrap enabled.

Comment: I have already looked at that datepicker, however I don't like the style of it, reason why I chose this one. On top of that, this one allows easy features addons such as (multidates etc) not sure If I can do the same with the one from bootstrap. If it's possible to change the style to look like the current one then it would be great.

Comment: Hi Giannis, I found a way to do it, please have a look at my starting post, at the end there's a solution. Feel free to advise if you think there's a better way.Thanks

Comment: That would be something i would have done too... Keep in mind i am new in Angular dev too, so there could be better solutions. But on the other hand, if that works....